# Subclasses and Storyboard - nil IBOutlets

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some troubles when subclassing a custom class with linked with a StoryBoard :/

So I have a class subclassing UIViewController

```
class MyClass: UIViewController
```

And some subclasses of `MyClass`

```
class MySubclassOne: MyClass
class MySubclassTwo: MyClass
```

`MyClass` design made in a StoryBoard `MyClass.storyboard`

`MyClass`implementation manage the basic respond to Layout changes (rotation, multitasking on iPad, scrolls…)

My subclasses do the rest (both do very different things)

QUESTION : How do I need to proceed to instantiate `MySuclassOne` so that the IBOutlets (in `MyClass`) are not nil ?

NOTE: I need to use a StoryBoard for many reasons - can't use a `.xib` file

---

EDIT: Some code explains it better

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet var lbl_title: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet var lbl_subtitle: UILabel!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      lbl_title.textColor = .red() // Execution error : lbl_title is nil
   }
}

class MySubclassOne: MyClass {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      lbl_subtitle.textColor = .orange()
   }
}

class MySubclassTwo: MyClass {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      lbl_subtitle.textColor = .green()
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to use the iboutlets of parent view into the child view?

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your storyboard
2. choose your view controller
3. select the "Identity inspector"
4. set your class to your class name (eg. MyClassOne)

[image]

Comment: No, it's set to `MyClass` not `MySubclassXXX`